# Как скрыть элекмент по условию в xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть свойство `cnt`, как я могу скрыть элемент когда `cnt > 5`?

Что-то типо тернарного оператора

```
Visibility="{Binding Path=Test.cnt > 5 ? 'Hidden' : 'Visibile'}"
```

Comment: Используйте конвертер значений.

Comment: @maxwell: Вы бы написали пример конвертера.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать конвертер значений.

> Это средство, позволяющее преобразовывать любой тип исходных данных в любой тип представления объекта, который может быть передан связанному элементу управления.

То есть преобразовать `int` к `Visibility` как в вашем случае.
 Более подробно можете прочитать [здесь](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/binding_and_styles_WPF/level20/20_1.php).

Конвертер будет выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
class CountToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int count;
        bool success = int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out count);
        if (!success)
        {
            return Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        if (count > 5)
            return Visibility.Hidden;

        if (count < 0)
            return Visibility.Collapsed;

        return Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Далее используем его в разметке:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <local:CountToVisibilityConverter x:Key="CountToVisibilityConverter" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <TextBox Text="{Binding Count, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <Button Content="Button1" Visibility="{Binding Count, Converter={StaticResource CountToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    <Button Content="Button2" />
</StackPanel>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! А куда обычно кладут такой класс? Отдельную папку создавать для конвертеров? Или пихать прямо в файл класса который предоставляет свойство `cnt`

Comment: @Fangog, Со временем таких конвертеров может накопиться достаточно много. Поэтому лучше создать отдельную папку.

Comment: А если я хочу сделать инверсию? Показывать либо один объект, либо другой. Создавать `InversionCountToVisibilityConverter`?

Comment: @Fangog, Если при одном и том же условии не могут быть отображены оба объекта, то да. Биндите оба объекта к свойству `Count` и задаете конвертер, в котором прописываете необходимую логику.